# Selecting rows from database that has over 25 words

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to select rows from my database that has over 25 words, but I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

```
SELECT input, LENGTH( input ) - LENGTH( REPLACE( input,  ' ',  '' ) ) +1 num
FROM confused
where num > '25'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Error:**

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'num' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Based on the answer to the other question you asked, do you understand what is wrong here or is it still confusing?

Comment: I guess he even more confused, as the proposed answer is unrelated to what he asks. The solution: Select * from (Select ... as num from confused) as innerTable where innerTable.num>25